# MySQLI 28000/1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having some trouble. So I am trying to connect to my database using MySQLi, but I am getting this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/venge/public_html/library/classes/database.class.php on line 16

Warning: Missing argument 1 for Users::__construct(), called in /home/venge/public_html/routing.php on line 4 and defined in /home/venge/public_html/library/classes/users.class.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/venge/public_html/library/classes/database.class.php on line 16

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/venge/public_html/library/classes/database.class.php:16) in /home/venge/public_html/routing.php on line 11
```

. I have no idea why it says "root" as the user, my code is below. I can login to PHPMyAdmin with that info fine.

```
<?php

$db['host'] = 'localhost';
$db['user'] = 'venge_main';
$db['pass'] = 'fakepassword';
$db['name'] = 'venge_panel';


class DB {
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['name']);
    }
    function query($i) {
        return $this->mysqli->query($i);
    }
    function fetch_array($i) {
        return $i->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
    function num($i) {
        return $i->num_rows;
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my global.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$venge['library'] = 'library/classes/';

include_once($venge['library'] . 'users.class.php');
include_once($venge['library'] . 'database.class.php');
$users = new Users($database);
?>
```

Here is my users class:

```
<?php
class Users {
    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = new DB($db);
    }
    public function uidset() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function securitycheck() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
            //passed
            return true;
        } else {
            //failed
            die('No permissions');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Here is routing.php:

```
<?php
class Routing {
    public function __construct($route) {
        $this->users = new Users();
        $this->route = $route;
    }
    public function File() {
        if (!$this->users->uidset()) {
            switch ($this->route) {
                default:
                    header("Location: /user/login");
                    break;
                case '/user/login':
                    include_once('library/pages/login.page.php');
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch ($this->route) {
                default:
                    header("Location: /venge");
                    break;
                case '/venge':
                    echo 'Welcome to <strong>Venge</strong> .';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

$route = new Routing($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']);

$route->File();
?>
```

Comment: Would you mind take a look at the column to the right titled "Related"? You may find it somewhat interesting.

Comment: if I am not mistaken, the line with mysqli connect is 11th one. Though error message states 16th. Are you sure you are running the right file?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I took out some comments, thats line 16.

Comment: @user2484067 Answer: `---Just keep going till you reach the end---->`

Comment: Show the code, where you are creating an instance of DB class. Maybe, the data is not passed to the constructor?

Comment: @user4035 I updated it with all the code,

Comment: `$db!=$database`.....

Comment: @Wrikken, where is that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error is here:

```
class Routing {
    public function __construct($route) {
        $this->users = new Users();//<-?
        $this->route = $route;
    }
```

You are not passing a parameter to Users.__construct($db)

Define an array with credentials and pass is like this:

```
class Routing {
    public function __construct($route) {
        $db = array();
        $db['host'] = 'localhost';
        $db['user'] = 'venge_main';
        $db['pass'] = 'fakepassword';
        $db['name'] = 'venge_panel';

        $this->users = new Users($db);
        $this->route = $route;
    }
```

Or use a global $db variable instead of defining it locally, like I did. But you must pass it to constructor when creating Users object.

### Error in global.php

```
$users = new Users($database);
```

I think, it must be:

```
$users = new Users($db);
```

If $db is defined in that file.

Comment: I have done what you said, but I still get `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/venge/public_html/library/classes/database.class.php on line 16

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/venge/public_html/library/classes/database.class.php:16) in /home/venge/public_html/routing.php on line 18`

Comment: @user2484067 Can you var_dump($db); in class DB function __construct($db). Isn't it passed? The headers error may be caused by extra text before `<?php` Even a newline character can cause it. Make sure, that you have `<?php` tags at the beginning of every file.

Comment: Not too worried about headers, but here is the dump: `NULL 
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/venge/public_html/library/classes/database.class.php on line 17
array(4) { ["host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["user"]=> string(10) "venge_main" ["pass"]=> string(7) "fakepassword" ["name"]=> string(11) "venge_panel" } 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/venge/public_html/library/classes/database.class.php:16) in /home/venge/public_html/routing.php on line 18`

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means that one of your `host`, `database`, `user` or `password` is wrong.

In my case it was the `host`, I usually use localhost but this time I saw in my `cPanel` > `MySQL® Databases` that I should not use localhost and istead I should use mysql5.xxxxxxx.net.

This was the message that helped me:

> The mysql server’s address is mysql5.xxxxxxxx.net. When connecting to
>   the mysql server you must specify this host.